# Recursive query for orphans in a non-hierarchical structure

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to figure out a recursive query, but my case doesn't quite fit into the examples I've seen. The table is a classic parent/child table. It has three fields: parent, child, and fco.

```
create table relationships (
    fco boolean,
    parent varchar(36),
    child varchar(36)
);
```

Now, the tricky part is that it isn't a hierarchy. Any object can reference any other object, even itself. So the data can be all tangled up. The fco field indicates "first class object", which means it doesn't have to be referenced by another object. The goal is to write a query that selects all the records that aren't referenced by an fco, and aren't referenced by a record that is referenced by an fco, etc. I'm trying to purge the orphans.

I've played around with writing recursive queries, but I'm just not getting anywhere. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is the SQL to create a complete working example. Also attached is a diagram of the structure, which, as you can see, is pretty tangled. The recursive select should select either everything in the green box (because it is all descended from "fruit" which is a first class object) or should select everything that *isn't* in the green box.

Note that java references fruit (an fco) but that shouldn't prevent it from being selected in the outside group. Referencing an fco doesn't keep a node from being an orphan... being referenced *by* an fco makes it not an orphan.

```
create table relationships (
    fco boolean default 0,
    parent varchar(36),
    child varchar(36)
);

insert into relationships(fco, parent, child) values(1, 'fruit', 'green');
insert into relationships(fco, parent, child) values(1, 'fruit', 'blue');
insert into relationships(fco, parent, child) values(1, 'fruit', 'purple');
insert into relationships(parent, child) values('green', 'kiwi');
insert into relationships(parent, child) values('green', 'kiwi');
insert into relationships(parent, child) values('green', 'granny-smith');
insert into relationships(parent, child) values('blue', 'blueberry');
insert into relationships(parent, child) values('blueberry', 'blue');
insert into relationships(parent, child) values('purple', 'plum');
insert into relationships(parent, child) values('granny-smith', 'blueberry');
insert into relationships(parent, child) values('paprika', 'plum');
insert into relationships(parent, child) values('java', 'fruit');
insert into relationships(parent, child) values('pepper', 'java');
insert into relationships(parent, child) values('pepper', 'matico');
insert into relationships(parent, child) values('matico', 'matico');
```

[image]

Comment: it always helps to add sample data (in form of insert statements, include all edge cases) and expected output, so that people have something to test with.

Comment: OK. I'll have that up soon.

Comment: That's a substantial update!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this already works for your case, but the following CTE will select everything in the green box (well, everything *except* the parent the query started with, currently):

```
WITH RECURSIVE ancestor(child) AS (
  SELECT child from relationships WHERE parent = 'fruit'
  UNION
  SELECT r.child from ancestor a INNER JOIN relationships r on r.parent = a.child
)
SELECT child FROM ancestor;
```

Result

```
green
blue
purple
granny-smith
kiwi
blueberry
plum
```

Online playground: https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-5e163706674709agk55ql6e5

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!